# Title, abstract, declaration is not showing

Tags: titles

I am a newbie to latex and writing my thesis in latex. The problem is all the other chapters are compiled and shows in the pdf except the title, abstract, declaration, and acknowledgments. What is the problem here? Can anyone please help me?

```
%% HEADER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%
%%
\newcommand{\hyperrefpdfauthor}{}
\newcommand{\hyperrefpdftitle}{}
\newcommand{\hyperrefpdfsubject}{}
\newcommand{\hyperrefpdfkeywords}{}
\newcommand{\hyperrefpdfborder}{0}
\documentclass{styles/wissdoc-kw-eng}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{rotating}

% % newer acronym packaged dont use bflabel anymore,
\providecommand\aclabelfont{} % the new command ist aclabelfont however, we also need to be backwards compatible so... we do it like this
\renewcommand{\aclabelfont}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill} % keine serifenlose schrift für acronym

% newer acronym packaged dont use bflabel anymore, to not fail the statement below provide the command if not existing
\providecommand\bflabel{} 
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\aclabelfont{#1}} 

%\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[FIGTOPCAP]{subfigure}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{listing}{htbp}{lop}[chapter]
\floatname{listing}{Listing}

\usepackage[hang,center,nooneline]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={small,sf}}
\captionsetup[table]{font={small,sf}}
\captionsetup[listing]{font={small,sf}}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{styles/etoolbox}


%% Normales LaTeX oder pdfLaTeX? %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% ==> Das neue if-Kommando "\ifpdf" wird an einigen wenigen
%% ==> Stellen benötigt, um die Kompatibilität zwischen
%% ==> LaTeX und pdfLaTeX herzustellen.
%\newif\ifpdf
%\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
%    \pdffalse              %%normales LaTeX wird ausgeführt
%\else
%    \pdfoutput=1
%    \pdftrue               %%pdfLaTeX wird ausgeführt
%\fi


%% Fonts für pdfLaTeX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% ==> Nur notwendig, falls keine cm-super-Fonts installiert
\ifpdf
    \usepackage{ae}       %%Benutzen Sie nur eines dieser Pakete:
    %\usepackage{zefonts}  %%je nachdem, welches Sie besitzen.
\else
    %%Normales LaTeX - keine speziellen Fontpackages notwendig
\fi


%% Deutsche Anpassungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% zur Zitaten des Quelltextes%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "final" forces printing of all listings, even if the global "draft" is set
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    tabsize=4,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbersep=5pt,
    numbers=left,
    captionpos=b,
    abovecaptionskip=0pt,
    belowcaptionskip=0pt,
    aboveskip=10pt,
    belowskip=0pt,
    floatplacement=tbp,
    frame=topline,
    framerule=.1pt,
    framesep = 3pt,
    }
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{\textbf{Listing}}
% This is only kept for backwards compatibility. You should never have to use it. Use the listing-environment instead.
%\DeclareCaptionFormat*{lstruled}{{\bfseries#1\small\space\normalfont#3\hrule height.1pt depth0pt}\par}
%\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=lstruled,singlelinecheck=false}

%% mehrere Abbildungen in eine %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{subfigure}

%% Packages für Formeln %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%% Zeilenabstand %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing        %% 1-zeilig (Standard)
%\onehalfspacing       %% 1,5-zeilig
%\doublespacing        %% 2-zeilig


%% Andere Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{a4wide} %%Kleinere Seitenränder = mehr Text pro Zeile.
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%Fancy Kopf- und Fußzeilen
%\usepackage{longtable} %%Für Tabellen, die eine Seite überschreiten
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating} 
%\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat} %Trennung von Typewriter-Schriften
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}

% Tabellen mit Center und left
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl} % colored table background
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
% Table spacings
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}\rule[-1.0ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.0ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\definecolor{slightgray}{gray}{.90} 
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}


%% Definitionen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%% zur Benutzung bei ergänzenden Daten%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{endnotes}
%\renewcommand{\notesname}{Konfigurationsdaten der Messreihen}
%\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\Alph{endnote}}
%\renewcommand{\enotesize}{\normalsize}

%\hyphenation{Sensor-netz-werk
%}
%TM-------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\q}[1]{``#1''}
\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic, graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOKUMENT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%% Dateiendungen für Grafiken %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% ==> Sie können hiermit die Dateiendung einer Grafik weglassen.
%% ==> Aus "\includegraphics{titel.eps}" wird "\includegraphics{titel}".
%% ==> Wenn Sie nunmehr 2 inhaltsgleiche Grafiken "titel.eps" und
%% ==> "titel.pdf" erstellen, wird jeweils nur die Grafik eingebunden,
%% ==> die von ihrem Compiler verarbeitet werden kann.
%% ==> pdfLaTeX benutzt "titel.pdf". LaTeX benutzt "titel.eps".
%\ifpdf
%    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
%\else
%    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
%\fi

\pagestyle{empty} %%Keine Kopf-/Fusszeilen auf den ersten Seiten.

\ifnotdraft{
%% Deckblatt %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter
\input{chapters/00_title}
\cleardoublepage
\input{chapters/00_declaration}
\cleardoublepage
\input{chapters/00_abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\input{chapters/00_acknowledgments}
\cleardoublepage

% Titelseite hatte noch normale Tabellen. Von hier ab sollen alle
% Tabellen laut style-Vorgaben sans serif sein.
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\sffamily}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\sffamily}

%% Inhaltsverzeichnis %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents %Inhaltsverzeichnis
\cleardoublepage %Das erste Kapitel soll auf einer ungeraden Seite beginnen.
} % end ifnotdraft

\pagestyle{fancy} %%Ab hier die Kopf-/Fusszeilen: headings / fancy / ...

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% einzelne Kapitel
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{commands}

\mainmatter
\input{chapters/01_introduction}
\input{chapters/02_background}
\input{chapters/03_related_work}
\input{chapters/04_rl}
\input{chapters/05_Results}
%\input{chapters/06_results}
\input{chapters/06_conclusion}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% LITERATUR UND ANDERE VERZEICHNISSE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Ein kleiner Abstand zu den Kapiteln im Inhaltsverzeichnis (toc)
\ifnotdraft{
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
\cleardoublepage
%% Literaturverzeichnis
\phantomsection % phantomsection wird benötigt, damit z.B. hyperref die richtige Seite verlinkt.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%\nocite{*} %Auch nicht-zitierte BibTeX-Einträge werden angezeigt.
\bibliography{literature/literature}%Eine Datei 'literatur.bib' wird hierfür benötigt.
\bibliographystyle{styles/acmurl}%Art der Ausgabe: plain / apalike / amsalpha / ...
}

%% Abbildungsverzeichnis
%\clearpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
%\listoffigures

%% Tabellenverzeichnis
%\clearpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
%\listoftables

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% ANHÄNGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\appendix
\input{chapters/99_appendix}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\input{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to TeX. 
What is the document class you are using? Is it a customised class file or available in internet (please add a link of the `documentclass` you are using in your code).

Comment: `documentclass` is there. `\documentclass{styles/wissdoc-kw-eng}`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I missed it even after checking twice, but I do not see any `\maketitle` command. Without it, you will not get any title/author unless you declare it otherwise. Also I do not see anything like `\documentclass{article}`

Hope this helps. Another suggestion, your code is really messy for a main file. You may want to use a style file and just import that package in your main file.